# Pandas merge multiple rows of duplicate ID data into one row

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data structure

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
¦  STAGE_ID ¦ EMP_ID     ¦ ATTR1_OLD_VAL ¦ ATTR1_NEW_VAL ¦ ATTR2_OLD_VAL ¦ ATTR2_NEW_VAL ¦ ATTR3_OLD_VAL ¦ ATTR3_NEW_VAL ¦
¦-----------+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------¦
¦         1 ¦       E001 ¦ xyz           ¦ pqr           ¦ mmm           ¦ nnn           ¦ zzz           ¦ aaa           ¦
¦         2 ¦       E001 ¦ 1234          ¦ abc           ¦ 123           ¦ jjj           ¦ iii           ¦ bb            ¦
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to repeat the merge based on the value of EMP_ID

I want this result:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
¦  STAGE_ID ¦ EMP_ID     ¦ ATTR1_OLD_VAL ¦ ATTR1_NEW_VAL ¦ ATTR2_OLD_VAL ¦ ATTR2_NEW_VAL ¦ ATTR3_OLD_VAL ¦ ATTR3_NEW_VAL ¦
¦-----------+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------¦
¦         1 ¦       E001 ¦ xyz;1234      ¦ pqr;abc       ¦ mmm;123       ¦ nnn;jjj       ¦ zzz;iii       ¦ aaa;bb        ¦
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried the following code:

```
data1 = data.groupby(by='EMP_ID').apply(lambda x: [';'.join(x['ATTR1_OLD_VAL'])])
```

But this code can only merge one column

Comment: Use `data1 = data.groupby(by=['EMP_ID']).agg(';'.join)`

Comment: One question - do you need first value per `STAGE_ID` and join all columns without `EMP_ID` per groups?

Comment: hi, I do not need 'STAGE_ID'

Comment: ok, so solution in comment working nice?

Comment: @jezrael Great solution!I can give you the right answer